# Why do I get an error when I try to add a dependent task to one created by the C plugin?

Tags: gradle

I have a build script that produces a native executable using the C plugin. When I attempt to add a dependent task (one that produces a flex output file from a flex input file), I either get an error or my dependent task isn't executed. I think what's happening is the declaration to add the dependent task is being evaluated before the model creates its tasks. If that's the case, then I'd need to know how to make the dependent task declaration more lazy (or perhaps add something to the model that I don't yet understand). Am I supposed to do this with a separate project?

Here is what I believe to be the essential part of the build script. I’ve commented out my attempts to declare the dependency.

```
$ cat build.gradle
apply plugin: 'c'

model {
    components {
        test(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                c {
                    source {
                        srcDir "."
                        include "*.c"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task compileLang (type: Exec) {
    inputs.file(project.file('test.l'))
    outputs.file(project.file('lex.test.c'))
    commandLine 'flex', '-f', '-L', '-8', '-i', '-P', 'test', 'test.l'
}

//buildDependentsTestExecutable.dependsOn compileLang
//project.task('buildDependentsTestExecutable').dependsOn compileLang
//project.tasks.getByName('buildDependentsTestExecutable').dependsOn compileLang
//tasks['buildDependentsTestExecutable'].dependsOn compileLang
```

These, I think, are the relevant tasks configured when I execute ‘gradle tasks’:

```
Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
installTestExecutable - Installs a development image of executable 'test:executable'
testExecutable - Assembles executable 'test:executable'.

Build Dependents tasks
----------------------
assembleDependentsTest - Assemble dependents of native executable 'test'.
assembleDependentsTestExecutable - Assemble dependents of executable 'test:executable'.
buildDependentsTest - Build dependents of native executable 'test'.
buildDependentsTestExecutable - Build dependents of executable 'test:executable'.
```

In the event that test.c and test.l are needed for someone to more easily answer the question...

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts("hello, world");
    testwrap();
}
$ cat test.l
%s OLC
%%
<INITIAL>-- {
    BEGIN(OLC);
}
<OLC>\n\r? {
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
}
<OLC>. {
}
%%
int yywrap () {
    return 1;
}
```

I'm using gradle 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task seems to be created at a later phase of the Gradle’s configuration phase.

I suggest adding a listener on the tasks container and it worked for me on your example:

```
project.tasks.whenObjectAdded { Task t -> 
    println 'Task added: ' + t.name
    if ('buildDependentsTestExecutable'.equals(t.name)) {
        t.dependsOn compileLang
    }
}
```

I’m not familiar with the ‘c’ plugin or with the model{} configuration, so my suggestion is based on the general familiarity I’ve with Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to define multiple projects, but I did have to define two build scripts. Of course, there is brittleness but at least it works.

This is `build.gradle`:

```
task LC (type: Exec) {
    inputs.file(project.file('test.l'))
    outputs.dir(buildDir)
    outputs.file("$buildDir/lex.test.c")
    commandLine 'flex', '-f', '-L', '-8', '-i', '-P', 'test', '-o', "$buildDir/lex.test.c", 'test.l'
}

task copyC (type: Copy) {
    from "."
    into buildDir
    include "*.c"
}

task build (type: GradleBuild) {
    dependsOn 'LC', 'copyC'
    buildFile = 'compileC.gradle'
    tasks = ['build']
}
```

And this is `compileC.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'c'

model {
    components {
        test(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                c {
                    source {
                        srcDir buildDir
                        include "*.c"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```